# MS Access Connection Option Not Available In Website Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

After clicking on **security** button in website administration tool, I am getting this error.

**There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.**

I am using Microsoft Access 2010 as my database.

Any solution.